Is a self-salting driveway plausible?
This Christmas Eve, I find myself daydreaming of a driveway made of a tough material, which contains a substantial quantity of NaCl or CaCl2 that is avidly bound to its structure above 1 C or so.  When the temperature is below that, the salt is released over some substantial surface area of contact with water.  In this way, the driveway would clear its entire surface of ice all winter, reabsorbing some of the salt during less rainy thaws, and you could spray brine on it during the summer until you saw dried salt or the conductivity of water sprayed onto the driveway afterward indicated it was saturated.  I'm thinking maybe a zeolite of some sort, but I have no idea really.  Could such a material really exist, or is it but a daydream?

What would prevent the salt from dissolving in rainwater and being carried away by the runoff? And what about sand? That is commonly used and can be (relatively) easily collected at the end of the winter season without risk of damage to environment and vehicles.

Heated driveways (hot water or electricity) are a thing. Expensive to run though, compared to paying the neighbors kids.

@BuckThorn - I was picturing a compound with a crystal structure that would somehow change to not bind Na and Cl tightly below 1 C (free energy to release them is close to zero, so you get substantial molar concentrations of salt at equilibrium then), but it would be very positive at elevated temperatures so that the driveway would scrounge up any salt from the environment in the summer.  Ideally it would contain internal water channels that allowed it to slowly redistribute the salt inside itself over time, so it neither releases it all at once nor is limited to surface ions.

If you're near the ocean, pump ocean water over the driveway -- as long as it's above salt-water's f.p.
